# Implicit equation of Semicircle and ellipse

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

May I know what is the Implicit equation to define the upper bound of a circle of radius 1?

Is it $ y^2 - \sqrt{1-x^2} = 0$?
and for the lower bound, $ y^2 + \sqrt{1-x^2} = 0$?

What is the implicit equation of the upper bound of an ellipse of radius 0.3 then?

Comment: Usually one just writes $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, $y \geq 0$, but of course on can solve *explicitly* for $x$ in this situation. It doesn't make sense to talk about a (general) ellipse of a given radius---one must specify both its semimajor and semiminor axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implicit equation of a circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin is $x^2+y^2=1$, so you can find: $y^2=1-x^2$ and the upper esmicircle ($y\ge 0$) is given by: $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ ( that you can write as $ y-\sqrt{1-x^2}=0$ if you want). The other semicircle ($y\le 0$) is $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

For an ellipse with center in the origin and symmetry axes parallel to the coordinate axis you can start from the equation 
$$
\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the semiaxis, and, in the same way, you find
$$
y=\pm\sqrt{b^2-\dfrac{b^2x^2}{a^2}}=\pm \dfrac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}
$$
that with the $+$ sign represent the upper ($y\ge 0$) semiellipse.

Finally, note has no sense to talk of an ellipse of radius $0.3$